# Is Oracle ADF a product line, and what makes it one?

Tags: architecture

I'm a master's degree student, studying software engineering, and I am wondering, and trying to find out why Oracle ADF is, or isn't, a product line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle ADF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Application_Development_Framework) is a product; not a product line. A product line is a group of products that a company creates under a single brand. Check some examples of product lines at https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/product-line.asp